# Second-Order Approximation to a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I am working with the following differential equation:

$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+z=\frac{\cos 2x}{1+\epsilon z},\:\:\:z(-\pi/4)=z(\pi/4)=0$

where modulus of $\epsilon$ is much less than $1$.  The task is then to use perturbation theory to show that the second-order approximation to the solution to this DE is:

$z=-\frac{1}{3}\cos 2x +\epsilon\bigg(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{45}\cos x - \frac{1}{90}\cos 4x \bigg) + \epsilon^2 \bigg(\frac{2\sqrt{2}x}{45}\sin x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{90}(\pi + 1)\cos x + \frac{7}{720} \cos 2x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{90}\cos 3x - \frac{1}{1050}\cos 6x \bigg).$

By starting point is to use the theory for a regular perturbation (since the modulus of $\epsilon$ is much less than $1$).  For the unperturbed equation, I could set $\epsilon=0$ as that would give a simple differential equation which should be solvable.  However, the next step is then to expand the solution as a power series, which is what I am less sure about.  I can do the computation with Maple if necessary, but would like to know the theory behind what is going on and some pointers as to how this all works.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon z}=1-\epsilon z+\epsilon^2 z^2+O(\epsilon^3)$ may be useful

Comment: Sorry if I am being slow, can you clarify how this works?  So do I solve the equation non-perturbatively first when $\epsilon=0$ and then multiply the answer with the above expansion to get second-order?

Comment: No, not like that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ z = z_0 + \epsilon z_1 + \epsilon^2 z_2 + O(\epsilon^3) $ then

\begin{align} \frac{1}{1+\epsilon z} &= 1 - \epsilon z + \epsilon^2z^2 + O(\epsilon^3) \\ 
&= 1 - \epsilon z_0 - \epsilon^2 z_1 + \epsilon^2{z_0}^2 + O(\epsilon^3)
\end{align}

Ignoring higher-order terms, the equation becomes
$$ {z_0}'' + z_0 + \epsilon({z_1}''+z_1) + \epsilon^2({z_2}''+z_2) = \big[ 1 - \epsilon z_0 + \epsilon^2({z_0}^2-z_1)\big]\cos 2x $$

Collecting like terms
$$ \big( {z_0}'' + z_0 - \cos 2x \big) + \epsilon\big({z_1}'' + z_1 + z_0\cos 2x \big) + \epsilon^2 \big[{z_2}'' + z_2 - ({z_0}^2-z_1)\cos 2x \big] = 0 $$

We obtain 3 equations
\begin{align}
{z_0}'' + z_0 - \cos 2x &= 0 \\
{z_1}'' + z_1 + z_0\cos 2x &= 0 \\
{z_2}'' + z_2 - ({z_0}^2-z_1)\cos 2x &= 0
\end{align}

Note that all boundary conditions are $z_i (-\pi/4) = z_i (\pi/4) = 0$

The constant peturbation gives $z_0 = -\frac13 \cos 2x$

The 1st order peturbation gives
$$ {z_1}'' + {z_1} = \frac13 \cos^2 2x = \frac16 (1 + \cos 4x) $$

Using undetermined coefficients, the particular solution is $z_{p1} = \frac16 - \frac{1}{90}\cos 4x$. After setting boundary conditions, we get $z_1 = \frac16 - \frac{1}{90}\cos 4x - \frac{8\sqrt{2}}{45}\cos x$

I'll leave you to find $z_2$. If the question doesn't ask to solve explicitly, you can also plug in the solution you were already given into the 3 peturbations.

Comment: when I solve this DE $  {z_0}'' + z_0 - cos 2x = 0 $.. I get $z_0 = sin(x)*_C2+cos(x)*_C1 - (1/3)*cos(2x) $.. is there a way to get only $\frac{1}{3}cos(2x)$

Comment: @ttz Use the boundary conditions

Answer (score 3):

The equation can be written as $$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+z=(1-\epsilon z+\epsilon^2z^2+O(\epsilon^3))\cos 2x$$First solve for the $\epsilon=0$ case, $$\frac{d^2z_0}{dx^2}+z_0=\cos 2x$$this should give the first term, which is $z_0=-\frac13 \cos2x$.

Next, look at the first order perturbation, $$\frac{d^2(z_0+\epsilon z_1)}{dx^2}+(z_0+\epsilon z_1)=(1-\epsilon (z_0+\epsilon z_1))\cos 2x\\\implies \frac{d^2z_1}{dx^2}+z_1=-z_0\cos 2x$$ and solve that, which should give you the second term in your answer, denoted $z_1$.

Finally study the equation with the $\epsilon^2$ terms,$$\frac{d^2(z_0+\epsilon z_1+\epsilon^2 z^2)}{dx^2}+(z_0+\epsilon z_1+\epsilon^2 z_2^2)=(1-\epsilon (z_0+\epsilon z_1+\epsilon^2 z_2^2)+\epsilon^2z_0^2+O(\epsilon^3))\cos 2x\\\implies \frac{d^2z_2}{dx^2}+z_2=(-z_1+z_0^2)\cos 2x$$ which should give the final term in your answer.

Comment: You should introduce indices for the components of the perturbation serise $z=z_0+ϵz_1+ϵ^2z_2+..:$. Then $$z_0''+z_0=\cos(2x)\\z_1''+z_1=-z_0\cos(2x)\\z_2''+z_2=(-z_1+z_0^2)\cos(2x)$$ etc.

Comment: @LutzL thanks, I have corrected it

Comment: Right, I get it now.  I think the textbook was phrased misleadingly, as it when it says 'solve the unperturbed equation in the $\epsilon =0$ limit, that is just to see if unperturbed solutions can be found in the first place, as you will obviously never find the perturbed ones otherwise.  Then you express the general solution as a power series and substitute in to get a hierarchical set of coupled ODEs.  Thanks for explaining this.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it, the "$\epsilon=0$ limit" thing is just to said to emphasise that you can write a solution like this as a power series.